# How to use Reflect. apply in TS

Tags: javascript, typescript

Tsc -Version 3.2.2

In ts ：

```
Reflect.apply(JSON.stringify,null,[{name: 'xx'}])
```

Error:

> Property 'apply' does not exist on type 'typeof Reflect'.

How to fix?

Comment: Please check browser compatibility: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Fix:

```
 (Reflect as any).apply().
```

You can read `antd` source code, Because it's written in React + TypeScript.

Comment: If you have to write that, the type declaration for reflect is wrong. furthermore, this is bad advice even if you don't take the time to locate a correct type definition because there are much better ways to say that reflect is a function, if it indeed is.